alguien sabe de una app para cambiar el collation de una bd?
estoy trabajando en workbench y uso el tf8mb4_general_ci pero les comparto es bd y pues con ellos no es compatible dicho collation lo que les permite trabajar a ellos es COLLATE=utf8_general_ci en xampp mi bd tiene demasiadas tablas he intendaro cambiar el collation desde el gestor  pero al exportar la bd regresa al collation de tf8mb4_general_ci y pues me resulta dificil estar cambiando en el script ya que son demasiadas tablas este es el problema cuando intentan importar la bd 



Muchos editores de texto soportan reemplazar, el propio bloc de notas lo hace, así como Notepad++, sublime text y muchos otros. Cambiar el collate en el script es tan fácil como sustituir el texto del collate incompatible por el nuevo y guardar el script actualizado.
